# error at closing database in customadapter?

Tags: android, database

I am trying to implement listview adapter, in adapter I wrote this code

```
try {
    dbhelper = new DBHelper(context);
    database=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String id = deviceid.toString().trim();                     
    String query = ("select POND, MAXVALUE ,MINVALUE,MAXPHVALUE,MINPHVALUE from ponddata  where  POND ='" + id + "'");
    cursor1 = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor1 != null){
        if(cursor1.moveToLast()){                                                        
            String maxvalue =cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("MAXVALUE"));
            String minvalue =cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("MINVALUE"));

            String maxphval = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("MAXPHVALUE"));
            String minphval = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("MINPHVALUE"));

            Float min = Float.parseFloat(minvalue);
            Float max = Float.parseFloat(maxvalue);
            ApplicationData.addmin(min);
            ApplicationData.addmax(max);

            Float min1=Float.parseFloat(minphval);
            Float max1=Float.parseFloat(maxphval);
            ApplicationData.addmin1(min1);
            ApplicationData.addmax1(max1); 
        }                           
        cursor1.moveToNext();   
    }   

} finally {
  cursor1.close();
  database.close();
}
```

but it showing error at cursor1.closse() database.close().
like fatal exception 
Process com.eample.test process :PID 11536
null pointer Exception  at adapter.getView.
Please any one help why its showing that error. I was trying to resolve this error from morning. please help.

Comment: where are you using that code? in the getView of the adapter?

Comment: yes, in getview of adapter